# how to change the style of the scrollbar of a TWebPanel in Delphi with TMS Web Core?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, tms-web-core

How can I change the style of the scrollbar of a TWebPanel (or a TWebScrollBox) ?
I would like to change opacity for example, or make it rounded and only visible when scrolling.

I tried to change some properties with ElementHandle.style

```
  WebPanel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('overflow-y','auto');
  WebPanel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('scrollbar-color','blue green') ;
  WebPanel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('scrollbar-width','thin') ;
```

but still I cannot change the opacity or border radius of the scrollbars.

And also, this works with Firefox but not with Chrome.

(I have the same results when using the TWebCSSClass component)

Any suggestion?

screenshot with Firefox:

[image: screenshot with Firefox]

screenshot with Chrome:

[image: screenshot with Chrome]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78212897/2908017

Comment: You solved it all through CSS. Your other wishes [can't be done with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color) - fading scrollbars are completely user-drawn and just mimic natural ones - likewise you must choose this way when wanting rounded corners and transparency. [Fx should support this CSS since version 64 (December 2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history#Firefox_60_through_67).